# Problem compiling bitcoin source code(https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) on linux

Tags: bitcoind

Issue: Problem compiling bitcoin source code from https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

Building bitcoin code requires Berkeley DB 4.8( https://github.com/tinybike/get-bdb-4.8).
No problem with that.

My system is running on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
$ cpp --version
cpp (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

When compiling the bitcoin code, after running 'configure' and 'make' an error occurs indicating that it could not find iostream.h

```
...
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-txrequest.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-txmempool.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-validation.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-validationinterface.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-versionbits.o
  CXX      wallet/libbitcoin_server_a-init.o
In file included from ./wallet/bdb.h:27,
                 from wallet/init.cpp:19:
/bitcoin/src/bdb/build_unix/build/include/db_cxx.h:59:10: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
   59 | #include <iostream.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:8933: wallet/libbitcoin_server_a-init.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/bitcoin/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:15214: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/bitcoin/src'
make: *** [Makefile:809: all-recursive] Error 1
```

On examining the header files location /usr/include/c++/9 I could not locate iostream.h

Is this a compiler package issue or bitcoin not using c++ iostream header file

Comment: Did you follow [the instructions](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md#ubuntu--debian)?

Comment: Yes I did. As I mentioned, I don't know if it's my compiler package missing iostream.h or bitcoin code not properly defining macro HAVE_CXX_STDHEADERS in /bitcoin/src/bdb/build_unix/build/include/db_cxx.h to use iostream

Comment: It's not Bitcoin's job to define HAVE_CXX_STDHEADERS. That's normally part of db_cxx.h (immediately before the #ifdef checking it). Something about your db4.8 build is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess you tried to build the "depends" BDB before installing the required system packages, and that produced an invalid/unusuable build.

Try removing your current "depends" builds and doing them over.

Alternatively, you could just use my db48 PPA for Ubuntu: [https://launchpad.net/~luke-jr/+archive/ubuntu/db48](https://launchpad.net/%7Eluke-jr/+archive/ubuntu/db48)

Comment: The required system packages specified in /bitcoin/doc/build-unix.md were all installed (except for the qt stuff) before the Berkeley DB 4.8 was built. The BDB built was successful.

Then the bitcoin code was built next

I'll try out the link you specified for Berkeley DB 4.8

Comment: The error you get means the BDB build was not successful. It produced an invalid db_cxx.h file.

Comment: I used your version of bdb4.8 from https://launchpad.net/~luke-jr/+archive/ubuntu/db48
and the compilation of bitcoin code was successful.
With that said the bdb4.8 from https://github.com/tinybike/get-bdb-4.8 was the source of the issue.
What's the diff in your version and why did you create it?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know what that random github repo does, but mine is just the original bdb4.8 package source code from Ubuntu (before they deleted it) with Java support removed (because it broke with newer Java stuff)

Answer (score -1):

i got the same error,but it came when i build zero-ice with berkeley db. I found some usages about libdb and most of them add `#define HAVE_CXX_STDHEADERS` at the begining of codes, so i tried add this definition in ICEDIR/cpp/include/IceUtil/Config.h. It works.Wish it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

something was completely wrong during db4.8 compilation
but as temporary fix, you may add in
include/db_cxx.h

#define   HAVE_CXX_STDHEADERS 1
this may help, but depends.

imho
most correct way to build db-4.8 for bitcoin

```
wget http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz
tar zxvf db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz
cd db-4.8.30.NC
build_unix/
../dist/configure --prefix=/usr/local/db48 --enable-cxx --with-pic --disable-replication --disable-shared
make install 
cd ../bitcoin-x.x
export BDB_PREFIX=/usr/local/db48
export BDB_LIBS="-L/usr/local/db48/lib -ldb_cxx-4.8"
export BDB_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/db48/include"
./configure
```

and etc.